# Background-repeat с низу в верх

Tags: jquery, css

Здравствуйте, есть блок у него background (картинки), которые повторяются по оси y, картинки по умолчанию повторяются с верху в низ а мне нужно чтоб картинки повторялись с низу в верх, чтобы самая нижняя картинка была целая и пристыковать к ней еще футер картинку. Никто не сталкивался с такой ситуацией?

[image]

Comment: Не совсем понял вопрос. Может, Вам background-position подойдёт?

Comment: @andreyqin, вот есть блок у него есть css background: url(../images/bg_popup.png) repeat-y; и вот картинки повторяющие на фоне по y начинаются с верху и заканчиваются с низу, и вот самая последняя картиинка всегда заканчиваются не целой, а мне нужна целая картинка чтоб пристыковать еще нижнюю картинку, понимаете:)

Comment: Ну, значит сделайте смещение сверху на необходимую величину при помощи background-position. Но тогда картинка сверху будет неполная.

Comment: @andreyqin,мм, ну да хорошая идея, вот только необходимую величину я не могу знать потому что высота блока зависит только от материалов который в нем есть.  Высоту блока вообще не смог узнать, я уже поднимал этот вопрос http://hashcode.ru/questions/235709/jquery-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-scroll-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BF-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82 , я думал может есть какие то другие ходы есть

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
background: url("your_image.jpg") center bottom repeat-y;
```

Comment: @dekameron, красава!!! Спасибо, блииин как я мучался доолго, я уже начал думать как сделать с помощью JS)) Спасибо!!!

Comment: @bemulima, прежде, чем юзать JS надо CSS хорошенько понасиловать))
Хотя, конкретно в этом случае, это даже насилием назвать сложно :)